# Can I reliably emplace_back in a vector of a type that does not have an assignment operator?

Tags: c++, vector, allocation, move-constructor, move-assignment-operator

I made some tests in GCC, Clang and MSVC and found out that `emplace_back` never calls an assignment operator on the contained class. It only calls the copy or move constructor when reallocation takes place. Is this behavior somehow guaranteed by the standard?

The use case is that I have some classes to be sequentially stored in a number that only grows along time until the whole vector is destructed. I'd be happy to clean my code from the assignment operators.

Comment: One easy way to find out would be to just *try* - delete the assignment operators and if the code still compiles; you're golden ;-)

Comment: @Jesper Juhl, it does compile, but I think it wouldn't only if some implementation actually called the assignment operator

Comment: @JesperJuhl: OP asks whether it is guaranteed by the standard. Working on a specific version of a specific compiler is not exactly the same thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These requirements are documented at cppreference.com.

For [`std::vector<T>::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) :

> **Type requirements**
>
> -`T` (the container's `element` type) must meet the requirements of *`MoveInsertable`* and *`EmplaceConstructible`*.

Additionally `std::vector` has a [general requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Template_parameters) that the type has to be *`Erasable`*.

[EmplaceConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EmplaceConstructible) requires that the type is constructible using the given allocator, with the arguments provided. Since you are using the default allocator `std::allocator<T>`, this just means that the type has an accessible constructor with those arguments.

[MoveInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable) requires that the type is constructible using the given allocator, using an rvalue of type `T`. For `std::allocator` this means that the type has an accessible move constructor.

[Erasable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Erasable) requires that the type is destructible using the given allocator. For `std::allocator` this means that is has an accessible destructor.

That's it (except for some rules about complete vs. incomplete types). There are no requirements that mention assignment operators.

But until C++11, it used to be that the type always had to be be *`CopyAssignable`* and *`CopyConstructible`*. This has since been relaxed. Now, except for *`Erasable`*, the requirements just depend on the operations performed on the vector.

Comment: `emplace_back` and move semantics are C++11 anyway, so isn't the point about older C++ standards somewhat irrelevant?

Comment: @Asu I think you're right regarding the conclusion, I'll remove it. Though I feel that mentioning the old requirement can help someone understand where the impression that an assignment operator is required might come from. Because it used to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, emplace back will call the move constructor provided one is available (or construct in place):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

struct Pt {
    Pt() = default;
    
    Pt& operator=(Pt const& other) = delete;
    
    Pt(Pt const&) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
    Pt(Pt&&){ std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    std::vector<Pt> v;
    
    v.emplace_back(Pt{});
   
    return 0;  
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5836d0278b97fdf7)

The actual [constraints applied to the type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) are for it to be [MoveInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable) and [EmplaceConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EmplaceConstructible)

Comment: Thanks. I had made similar tests. Will try to understand if these constraints imply the assignment operator or not.

Comment: @really No, they do not. Constraints related to assignment are named "..Assignable". Assignment operator can be a fallback when other stuff don't exist, so all these constraints say is your type has to provide a set of other properties

Answer (score 1):

This is what [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) about `emplace_back`:

> - `T` (the container's element type) must meet the requirements of *MoveInsertable* and *EmplaceConstructible*.

For [*EmplaceConstructible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EmplaceConstructible), the requirement is for `std::allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, args);` to be valid. This is the boring constraint only useful for actually emplacing elements.

*MoveInsertable* appears to be the concept required for reallocation to be possible.
For [*MoveInsertable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable), the requirement is for `std::allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, rv);` to be valid, where `rv` is a rvalue expression of type `T` (i.e. your type).

[`construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct)'s definition is sort of confusing but for most intents and purposes, it seems to be mere parameter forwarding to the constructor.

In other words, these two concepts seem to confirm that the only constraints to `emplace_back` is that you need to provide:

- the actual constructor that lets you construct in-place (duh)
- the move constructor (or copy if missing) for relocation when reallocation happens